# Segmentation fault when trying to embed Python module in C/C++ application. Beginner help needed

Tags: c, linux, python-3.x, cython, python-embedding

What I am trying to do is create a simple "Hello world" example that embeds a Python/Cython function in an application written in C. I want to embed also the Python interpreter so that the application doesn't have any external dependency. This is part of a larger project to utilize Python code in a C/C++ application, but I wanted to create a simple example first to learn the fundamentals. The final application is called `demo` and it simply calls a function called `helloworld`, which is written in Cython. The `helloworld` function simply prints "Hello world!" (obviously...).

My problem is I'm getting a segmentation fault when running the `demo` executable.

I've based my example largely on [this tutorial](http://www.discoversdk.com/blog/cython-advanced-topics). I had to modify the example a bit, since it didn't compile (i.e. cython command threw an error) the first time around. Here is the complete code and set of commands that I ran:

### helloworld.pyx

```
cdef public void helloworld():
   print("Hello world!")
```

### demo.c

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "helloworld.h"

int main () {

   Py_Initialize ();
   PyInit_helloworld ();

   // Call the Cython function
   helloworld ();

   Py_Finalize ();
   return 0;
}
```

Commands used to compile:

```sh
$ cython -3 helloworld.pyx
$ gcc -g -fpic -c helloworld.c -o helloworld.o `python3.6-config --includes`
$ gcc -g -fpic -c demo.c -o demo.o `python3.6-config --includes`
$ gcc -g -o demo helloworld.o demo.o `python3.6-config --libs` -L /home/rob/anaconda3/lib
```

However, when running `demo`, I get the following:

```sh
$ ./demo
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Digging a bit deeper:

```sh
$ gdb demo
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git
[output truncated]
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/rob/cython_test/demo 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555569cb in __Pyx_PyObject_Call (func=0x0, arg=0x0, kw=0x0) at helloworld.c:1493
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
1493        ternaryfunc call = func->ob_type->tp_call;
```

In case it is relevant, here is the output of the `python3.6-config` commands embedded in the `gcc` flags:

```sh
$ python3.6-config --includes
-I/home/rob/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -I/home/rob/anaconda3/include/python3.6m
$ python3.6-config --libs
-lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lrt -lm
```

I have also tried compiling the above using the "system" install of Python, since I was a little suspicious that the Anaconda distribution was causing my problems, but the result was entirely the same.

Comment: `PyInit_helloworld` returns a `PyObject*` or `NULL` on error. Adding a check for that might be worthwhile (probably not, but maybe)

Comment: Cannot reproduce, the example runs correctly for me. If you have an Anaconda installation under your user directory, try removing it from LD_LIBRARY_PATH.